# Scala macro deprecated

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-2.12

I start learning this complex feature of Scala, but recently I went to Scala days and Martin Odersky mention that scala macro was an experiment and now is deprecated.
Then I had no chance to ask what similar feature we will have Instead
of macros, or if it's worth it learn it and use it until that day happens(next week, the next decade)?

Regards.

Comment: scala macros have always been an experimental feature, as many other features including implicit conversions. They're not going to be deprecated as a feature, but the current implementation will likely be replaced by one based scala.meta

Comment: Scala.meta? I cannot find any official documentation about it. Would you so kind to paste here some reference documentation please? Regards

Comment: Sure, here's the official website http://scalameta.org/ and here's a tutorial about macro annotations http://scalameta.org/tutorial/#Macroannotations